# Dependency failed for /dev/disk/

Tags: 16.04, fsck

**UPDATE:**

I was not convinced it was my had disk at fault as per discussion below so after investigating (see sub-thread: [Is my Fstab ok?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921127/is-my-fstab-ok)) I ended up replacing Ubuntu with Linux Mint. And the problem of random crashes seems to have gone away (been using it heavy-duty for a good couple of hours by which time Ubuntu would have normally crashed on me).

I know that's not a great answer but I did try hard to figure out what was going on and came out with naught. Mint is also based on Ubuntu 16.04 which makes it even more puzzling.

**Original post:**

This may or may not be a disk error as getting mixed results from my checks - happy to have it flagged as a duplicate until I have time to resolve it.

---

I recently started developing problems with Ubuntu 16.10 where it either freezes or the screen goes funny (buttons becomes fuzzy or disappear) and there's no way of rebooting other than holding down the power button.

I tried removing and installing 16.04 instead but the same issue. So then I went into recovery mode and ran fsck and got

[image: screenshot]

This then paused a for a while before flashing up more error yellow errors that I didn't have time to read before going black and freezing

So then I used my USB image and logged into Ubuntu from there and ran fsck on both the main and swap partitions. This time round it indicated both were fine (main was deemed 'clean' and Swap gave some non-meaningful message that I can't remember -- something like 'fsck is version xxx'

So now I'm at a loss as my laptop still keeps crashing after about 10 minutes of use.

Comment: Try using Hiren's Boot to scan the disk. There are some tools on it that let you do that. My favourite is Victoria (accessible in Mini Windows XP) as it has nice GUI and can remap bad sectors.

Comment: Thanks will check it out. Right now my solution has been to repartition my drive to move my Ubuntu install to a different location. It's been more than 10 minutes and no crashes so far so fingers crossed. But will still want to do a complete scan.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how to use Victoria - it seemed very complicated but AOMEI Partition Assistant had a partition checking tool which seems to indicate my disks are fine. The error did come back again when I was using Ubuntu yesterday. I'm going to have investigate more fully in a week or so once I've got a deadline out the way. For now I've switched over to my windows partition and using that.

Comment: When you launch Victroria you select your drive and go to `Tests` tab press `Remap` radio button (optional; it will automatically remap any bad sector it finds any), press big `Start` button and wait for it to finsh. It should report bad sectors with yellow `x` on blue background. Also in `SMART` tab there is `Ultra DMA CRC errors` and `Offline scan UNC errors` fields that indicate if your drive encountered any  unrecoverable errors before. If it is not zero then something is wrong with the drive.